# Populate Angular Chart from watcher - Weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chart

I have the problem that my angular-chart is not displaying data when updated from the factory broadcast. I am setting labels and data like such, based on user input this might change:

```
// Listener function in controller, receives data from factory
$scope.$on("New Data", function(event, data, ID) {
        processTripData(data, ID).then(function(result) {
            setTypeDistributionBar(result).then(function(r) {
                buildTypeDistributionBar(r.data, r.labels);
            })
        })
    })
var buildTypeDistributionBar = function(data, labels) {
        $scope.distributionLabels = labels;
        $scope.distributionData = [data];
    }
```

The problem is that this only updates the chart after the second call of `buildTypeDistributionBar`. So this chart is always 1 query behind what the user puts in.

Question: Why is the chart only showing after this has been called a second time? How can I achieve that it updates immediately?

Update: I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vz4qhqpw/419/) to demonstrate this, it doesn't show the same behaviour like I have, but similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that this just might be a `scope` related issue, and the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776502/angularjs-data-one-step-behind) lead me to the following, which works. Basically the `$scope.$apply();` forces a digest. Now the chart isn't one step behind anymore:

```
var buildTypeDistributionBar = function(data, labels) {
        $scope.distributionLabels = labels;
        $scope.distributionData = [data];
        $scope.$apply();
}
```